# Need full example for jqgrid with struts2

Tags: json, struts2, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid plugin in struts2.I am able to see *JSON* data in browser but not sure how to show that data in grid (using grid.jsp).

Below are the files I am using:

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="getJSONResult" class="com.developer.am.action.JSONDataAction">
        <result type="json" />
    </action>

    <action name="ListUsers" class="com.developer.am.action.ListUsersAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS">grid.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    Struts2_Json
    
        index.jsp

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**JSONDataAction.java**

```
package com.developer.am.action; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class JSONDataAction{


int id = 1;
String firstName = "ASHOK";
String lastName = "BHOR";
String username = "ab";
String email="ab@.com";

        /*setter getter methos */

        }
```

**ListUsersAction.java**

```
package com.developer.am.action;

public class ListUsersAction {
     public String execute() {
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="st" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<st:form action="getJSONResult">

<h1>Hello</h1>
<st:submit value="ok"></st:submit>
</st:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**grid.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>List Users</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery().ready(function (){
    alert('Hi');
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
           url:'Struts2_Json/getJSONResult.action',
        datatype: "json",
           colNames:['User Id','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username','Email'],
           colModel:[
               {name:'id',index:'id', width:75},
               {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:90},
               {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100},
               {name:'username',index:'username', width:80},
               {name:'email',index:'username', width:80}                   
           ],
           rowNum:10,
           autowidth: true,
           rowList:[10,20,30],
           pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
           sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Users"
    }).navGrid('#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});    
});                
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list1"></table>
    hi
    <div id="pager1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's one thing that I see that you will want to change: I believe that the `index` value in the `colModel` array should be an integer, not a string.  And something that will help you to debug this: make sure that JSONDataAction.java is giving you valid JSON, structured the way that your JSP expects it to be.  It's hard to verify this fact, given the code that you have posted here.

Comment: Hi @DavidGorsline Can you please suggest on the below : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881679/recieving-json-data-on-server-but-not-able-to-display-it-in-jqgrid

Answer (score 1):

I know its pretty late but still posting answer.As if anyone face the same problem so he can get help here.

Recently have faced same issue and I solved it by using jsonReader property of free-jqGrid.

## Json I got from backend is

```
 "gridModel1": [{
        "description": null,
        "filterLang": "en",
        "filterName": "welcome1",
        "filterType": "Announcement",
        "id": {
            "customer": "DemoCust",
            "languageId": "en",
            "name": "welcome1",
            "poolName": "w",
            "customerId": "23",
            "type": "Prompt",
            "version": "default"
        },
        "key": "xxyzz123",
        "numId": 1,
        "usedForReport": false,
        "value": "http:\/\/15.213.57.179:8080\/mcm\/resources\/Djezzy\/Questionnaire\/Versions\/default\/DemoCust\/Prompt\/en\/welcome1.wav"
    }
```

## Using jsonReader property in jqGrid

```
$("#gridMod").jqGrid({
            url:"<<StrutsBackendCall>>",     
            datatype:"json",
            jsonReader: {
                root:"gridModel1"
            },
            colModel: [
                { name: "numId",index:"numId", label:"NumId" },

                { name: "filterName",index:"filterName", hidden:true, label:"id.Name"},

                { name: "id.poolName",index:"id.poolName",label:"Prompt Name" },
                { name: "id.name",index:"id.name", label:".wav File Name" },

                { name: "id.customerid",index:"id.customerid", hidden:true, label: "Tenant" }, 
                .....

            ],             
            /* loadonce:false, */
            guiStyle: "bootstrap",
            iconSet: "glyph",   
            sortorder: "asc",
            idPrefix: "gridModel1_",
            onSelectRowTopics:"rowselect_main1",
            pager: true,                
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
            rowNum:10,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "The grid, which uses predefined formatters and templates"
  )};
```

and now I am able to see data in grid.If its not clear ,please comment will try to help.