# Recieving JSON data on server but not able to display it in jqgrid

Tags: java, json, ajax, struts2, jqgrid

Not able to display the json data on jsp using **jqgrid**.

Need help eagarly.

Please find my JSP below:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>List Users</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery().ready(function (){
    //alert('Hi');
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
           url:'dataTablesAction',
        datatype: "json",
           colNames:['User Id','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username','Email'],
           colModel:[
               {name:'name',index:'name', width:75},
               {name:'rowId',index:'rowId', width:90},
               {name:'task',index:'task', width:100},
               {name:'taskTime',index:'taskTime', width:80},
               {name:'uId',index:'uId', width:80}                   
           ],
           rowNum:10,
           autowidth: true,
           rowList:[10,20,30],
           pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
           sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
       // sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Users"
    }).navGrid('#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});    
});                
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list1"></table>
    <div id="pager1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Action:

public class TaskViewAction implements Action {

```
private List<DailyTasks> detailsList;

public List<DailyTasks> getDetailsList() {
    return detailsList;
}

public void setDetailsList(List<DailyTasks> detailsList) {
    this.detailsList = detailsList;
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    detailsList = ExcelServices.readFromExcel("U:\\test.xlsx");

    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

}

Struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="json-default">
        <action name="dataTablesAction" class="com.action.TaskViewAction">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
                <param name="noCache">true</param>
            </result>
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I am receiving data in browser's console. I have checked this from developer's tool present in chrome.

Also there are no errors or exceptions.

Do I have to make changes in JSP?

Comment: Also I could see balnk GRID in browser with 0 pages in that.

Comment: The code doesn't fit a collumn model of jqGrid. You can use  struts2-jquery-grid plugin that removes the above errors.

Comment: Hey @RomanC thanks for your response. I have one doubt, does this plugin work for CRUD operations?
Also can you suggest the perfect example or demo of this?

Comment: Post errors and exceptions stacktrace.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I have mentionedd already...I am not getting any error or exceptions.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.